# Multi option filter from selection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a search form to filter out accounts to show their transactions using relations. I have it working to filter a single account. I need to create the filter multiple accounts together. Here is my code for filtering a single selection since I am ne to Laravel< I am getting stuck. Thanks in advance.

```
   public $relations = [];
public function account($account)
{ 
       return $this->where('account_id', $account);
}   }
```

This is my form:-

```
   {!! Form::open(['url' => 'incomes/revenues', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
<div class="pull-left">
    <span class="title-filter hidden-xs">{{ trans('general.search') }}:</span>
    <!--{!! Form::text('search', request('search'), ['class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm', 'placeholder' => trans('general.search_placeholder')]) !!}-->
    {!! Form::text('start', request('start'), ['class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm', 'placeholder' => trans('general.date_placeholder')]) !!}
    {!! Form::text('end', request('end'), ['class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm', 'placeholder' => trans('general.date_placeholder')]) !!}
    {!! Form::select('customer', $customers, request('customer'), ['class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('category', $categories, request('category'), ['class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('account', $accounts, request('account'), ['multiple' => 'true','class' => 'form-control input-filter input-sm']) !!}
    {!! Form::button('<span class="fa fa-filter"></span> &nbsp;' . trans('general.filter'), ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default btn-filter']) !!}
```

controller

```
    public function index()
{
    $revenues = Revenue::with(['account', 'category', 'customer'])->isNotTransfer()->collect(['paid_at'=> 'desc']);

    $customers = collect(Customer::enabled()->pluck('name', 'id'))
        ->prepend(trans('general.all_type', ['type' => trans_choice('general.customers', 2)]), '');

    $categories = collect(Category::enabled()->type('income')->pluck('name', 'id'))
        ->prepend(trans('general.all_type', ['type' => trans_choice('general.categories', 2)]), '');

    $accounts = collect(Account::enabled()->pluck('name', 'id'))
        ->prepend(trans('general.all_type', ['type' => trans_choice('general.accounts', 2)]), '');

    $transfer_cat_id = Category::transfer();

    return view('incomes.revenues.index', compact('revenues', 'customers', 'categories', 'accounts', 'transfer_cat_id'));
}
```

Comment: You can't filter accounts with the query of specific account id.

If your using eloquent try using $accounts = Account:all();

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that calls this, and handles what is returned. Please add to your question. Then select all the code and type control-K to have it automatically formatted properly. This will help you get more interest in the question and more potential answerers.

Comment: If I understood your question very well, I think you may use `whereIn` instead of `where` and pass an array of `account_id` you want to filter